# Orbit and pan not working with Middle mouse button

Tags: 3d-view, navigation

I am using Blender 3.4. I cannot orbit or pan with my middle mouse button.i use Lenovo ThinkPad t480. I tried enabling emulate 3 button mouse. After that I could orbit but pan didn't work. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Hi. Are you holding down the Shift key when you try to pan?

Comment: How are you panning?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.